# How to take xpath to Get Text from class inside th

Tags: xpath

I have the following XPath :

```
//table[@class='ui-jqgrid-htable']/thead/tr/th//text()
```

And I'm trying to get the text from it with the following command :

```
String LabelName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-jqgrid htable']/thead/tr/th//text()")).getText()
```

But it's not printing text, the result is blank. Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

The `text()` in your xpath does not qualify as an element. Your element ends at `//table[@class='ui-jqgrid-htable']/thead/tr/th`. Try using `getText()` for this XPath.

Also, a table would have many headers. Using `findElement` will only return the first one.
If you want to get all headers use

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-jqgrid-htable']/thead/tr/th"))
```

and loop through the list to `getText` of individual element.